# Best way to combine json files into one

Tags: python, json

I have json files with same names in different folders in folder structure mentioned below

```
folder1/
    file1.json
    file2.json
    file3.json
folder2/
    file1.json
    file2.json
    file3.json
    file4.json
folder3/
    file1.json
    file2.json
    file3.json
    file4.json
    file5.json
....
```

What is the best way to combine json files available in all the folders to create a single json file. The keys in `file1.json` is unique across all the folders that it exists in

So far, I could think of the following approach but it feels slow since each json file is around 5 MB.

```py
from pathlib import Path

output_dir = Path(location_of_output_folder)
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# find all the folders
root_dir = Path(root_location_for_folders)
folders = [fld for fld in root_dir.iterdir() if fld.is_dir()]

# find all the unique file names
all_filenames = []
for fld in folders:
    for f in fld.glob('*.json'):
        all_filenames.append(f.name)


## Approach 1
# Join file that possibly exists across all the folders by creating empty list
for f in list(set(all_filenames)):
    f_data = []

    for fld in folders:
        if (fld / f).is_file():
           with open(fld /f, 'r') as fp:
               f_data.append(json.load(fp))

    with open(output_dir / f, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(f_data, fp, indent=4)


## Approach 2
# Join file that possibly exists across all the folders by creating empty dict
for f in list(set(all_filenames)):
    f_data = {}

    for fld in folders:
        if (fld / f).is_file():
           with open(fld /f, 'r') as fp:
               f_data.update(json.load(fp))

    with open(output_dir / f, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(f_data, fp, indent=4)
```

Is there a better(faster) way to this. I am only worried about the time and not interested in a pythonic solution

Thanks

Update #1: The files that have same filename should be merged. Sorry if I was not clear on that. Each file will have few keys `(l1, l2, l3, l4)` that are similar with all the files

Example

a. structure of `file1.json` in `folder1`

```
{
    k1: {
           l1: 11,
           l2: 12,
           l3: 13,
           l4: 14,
        },

    k2: {
           l1: 21,
           l2: 22,
           l3: 23,
           l4: 24,
        }
    .....
}
```

a. structure of `file2.json` in `folder2`

```
{
    k8: {
           l1: 41,
           l2: 42,
           l3: 43,
           l4: 44,
        },

    k9: {
           l1: 51,
           l2: 52,
           l3: 53,
           l4: 54,
        }
    .....
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's really anything better than loading all the files and then dumping the result. Trying to do it by merging the files directly will not work, because it doesn't respect JSON syntax.

Comment: Can you share some example JSON? _I am only worried about the time and not interested in a pythonic solution_ Huh, why is that?

Comment: Wait are you trying to merge the files with the same name? It isn't clear in your post.

Comment: @AMC I updated the question to include more information

Comment: @RTM okay so files with the same name are merged. Is there one of each file name (type/category?) in each folder?

Comment: @AMC There is no requirement that each file name should exist in each folder. For example, in the example shown in the question, `file5.json` doesn't exist in `folder1` and `folder2`

Comment: @RTM Ah right, yes. You already wrote that the keys are unique, so I’m guessing you want us to merge the dictionaries, not just create a list of them? I want to be sure I can test my solution thoroughly.

Comment: @AMC Yeah. Something like approach 2 is more ideal solution. If I have to make list from contents of file located in each folder, I would have to list of dictionaries to single dictionary later to maintain the consistency in the format of combined file and individual files

Comment: Sorry but it is still not clear: 'file1.json' in 'folder1' got keys 'k1, k2..' and 'file2.json" in 'folder2' has different keys. OK but does 'file1.json' in 'folder2' and other folders have the same keys as the first 'file1.json' ? If is is the case, what do you means by "merge", should all values be concatenated for each corresponding key?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Each file has different keys (k1, k2 etc.), but the nested keys are same (l1, l2 etc.). What I meant by merging is have a json file with keys (k1, k2, k8, k9 etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse your input JSON file but simply read them as text files, which would be MUCH faster (it's basically one system call per file). Then combine them into a global JSON list by adding a `[` at the beginning, a `]` at the end, and a `,` after each file content. OK, the lines will not be indented for the level-0 list, but who cares? Here is a skeleton implementation:

```
infiles = [...] # the whole list of input JSON files
outfile = 'out.json'

with open(outfile,'w') as o:
    o.write('[')
    for infile in infiles[:-1]: # loop over all files except the last one
        with open(infile,'r') as i:
            o.write(i.read().strip() + ',\n')
    with open(infiles[-1]) as i: # special treatement for last file
        o.write(i.read().strip() + ']\n')
```

Note that this implementation stores the input files one-by-one in RAM, so a very long list of files is easily handled, contrary to other approaches.

Last point: if you REALLY want indentation for all inner lines, you could simply read each file line-by-line (using the `readline()` method on files) and prefix
by 4 spaces before writing on output file. But you will loose performance...

**EDIT:** A slightly modified version with more code factorization

```
infiles = [...] # the whole list of input JSON files
outfile = 'out.json'
end, n = (']\n', ',\n'), len(infiles)

with open(outfile, 'w') as o:
  o.write('[')
  for infile in infiles:
    n -= 1
    with open(infile, 'r') as i:
      o.write(i.read().strip() + end[n>0]) # select correct end separator
```

Comment: Is `json.load` and `json.dump` slower than `i.read` and `o.write` ?

Comment: @RTM: I made some quick benchmarking : for complex JSON structures, you may have between 2x and 2.5x speedup with `i.read()` compared to `json.load()`.

Comment: Further benchmarking : and even a 5x speedup for a VERY complex (27k lines) JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest code I could come up with:

```py
from glob import glob
from os import makedirs, path
from pathlib import Path
import json

# Directories
input_dir = "in"
output_file = "out/out.json"

# Get array of files
files = glob(path.join(input_dir, "**", "*.json"))

# Data object
data = {}

# Merge all files
for file in files:
    data.update(json.load(open(file)))

# Create output directory
makedirs(path.dirname(output_file), exist_ok=True)

# Dump data
json.dump(data, open(output_file, "w+"))
```

Comment: Can't `dict(data, **json.load(open(file)))` be replaced by `data.update()`? Also, why aren't you using a context manager for that file?

Comment: @Richie Sorry for not being more clear on the question. I am looking to only add contents of `file1.json` across all folders,  `file2.json` across all folders and so on

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I am aware that this solution no longer fits the requirements, I will update it shortly.

Putting aside the issue of whether or not this matters for the moment, here is what I came up with.

```py
import glob
import json

file_names = glob.glob('../resources/json_files/*.json')

json_list = []

for curr_f_name in file_names:
    with open(curr_f_name) as curr_f_obj:
        json_list.append(json.load(curr_f_obj))

with open('../out/json_merge_out.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(json_list, out_file, indent=4)
```

The directory of JSON files contained:

`example_1.json`:

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

`example_2.json`:

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Contents of the output file, `json_merge_out.json`:

```
[
    {
        "quiz": {
            "sport": {
                "q1": {
                    "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                    "options": [
                        "New York Bulls",
                        "Los Angeles Kings",
                        "Golden State Warriros",
                        "Huston Rocket"
                    ],
                    "answer": "Huston Rocket"
                }
            },
            "maths": {
                "q1": {
                    "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                    "options": [
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12",
                        "13"
                    ],
                    "answer": "12"
                },
                "q2": {
                    "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                    "options": [
                        "1",
                        "2",
                        "3",
                        "4"
                    ],
                    "answer": "4"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "fruit": "Apple",
        "size": "Large",
        "color": "Red"
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are really interested about the time go straight to C++ or C. Like @Barmar said in the comment I don't think their will be much optimization you can do with your setup since you will need to open all the file anyway